# Testing an if statement -- AngularJS/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, code-coverage

Trying to access this if statement but my coverage is saying I'm not. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: configService', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('Service'));

  var configService, scope, httpBackend, results, tstConfigObj;
  var tstConfig = {
    "confLocation": "local-dev-conf.json"
  };

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function(_configService_, $httpBackend, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    configService = _configService_;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    // $rootScope.configObj = tstConfigObj;

    spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.callThrough();

    httpBackend.when('GET', 'conf.json').respond(200, tstConfig);
    httpBackend.when('GET', 'local-dev-conf.json').respond(200, {});

  }));

  describe('Function getConfig():', function() {

    it('should check if it was called', inject(function() {
      configService.getConfig();
      httpBackend.flush();

      expect(configService.getConfig).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

    it('should check if statement', inject(function() {
      scope.configObj = "Tesla is awesome";
      results = scope.configObj;
      configService.getConfig();
      httpBackend.flush();
      expect(results).not.toBe(null);
    }));
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

I need to make `configObj != null`, but struggling to do so. Something wrong with my scope maybe?

Here's my coverage:
[image: coverage]

EDIT: Fixed by passing `configObj` in the function:

`getConfig: function(configObj) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your configObj variable is local, so when you call `scope.configObj = "Something"` it will not change the variable you want to change. Try putting it in the return statement as a variable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I assume you mean defining configObj after the return statement it is directly above? If so, it throws an error unfortunately

Comment: Is this not working?
`return {
configObj: null,
// your other code`